# Can not give any access using Docker

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I create an image that is under my username namespace. I make the repository private then i add a collaborator. I see that the collaborator is added but he still can not find my image on docker hub. I have a free account on docker hub.

Does the free account of docker hub allow sharing a repository with collaborators? and if you yes do you have an idea why he does not find the repository on docker?

Comment: do you see your own image in the repo?

Comment: @Anonymous even me i can not see it when i look for it through the search bar. But i can see it on my repositories